# docker compose environment variable to IConfiguration, how to do?

Tags: c#, docker-compose, azure-active-directory, environment-variables, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using docker compose file to keep all the environment variables,

```
environment:
  - Instance=https://login.microsoftonline.com/
  - ClientId=xxxxxxxx
```

and I can access these variables in my asp.net core web api app `statrtup` class like below,

```
var instance = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Instance")
var clientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClientId")
```

In `statrtup` class I can send the entire like below `IConfiguration` to some method like,

```
services.AddProtectedWebApi(Configuration);
```

where it will automatically read all the configuration what I have configured in `AzureAd` section of `appsettings.json`

```
"AzureAd": {
"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
"ClientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"Domain": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"TenantId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

},

Now my question is, how we can read environment variables (instead of `appsettings.json`) and prepare `IConfiguration` with config section `AzureAd`?

Comment: Are you asking how to make a class that reads environment variables, and also implements an interface (IConfiguration) and pass it to a method? It seems like you already know how to do these things?

Comment: how to convert override values of appsettings that's comes from env. variables

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#environment-variables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following environment variable names with prefix:

```
environment:
- AzureAd__Instance=https://login.microsoftonline.com/
- AzureAd__ClientId=xxxxxxxx
```

to override `appsettings.json`